# Filtering by date does not show the filter selection

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I made a macro that filters three columns. I get only blank fields.

After going manually into the three filter selections (which the macro has done) and clicking "OK" on all three, the data is displayed.

Date format: 02.01.2023

```vb
Sub Filter_Date()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Source Data")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A12:AA2758")
    
    rg.AutoFilter 25, "<=" & DateSerial(2023, 12, 30), xlAnd, "<>" & DateSerial(2022, 12, 31)
    rg.AutoFilter 26, "<=" & Date + 7, xlOr, "unconfirmed"
    rg.AutoFilter 27, "<=" & Date - 5
        
End Sub
```

[image: p]

Answer (score 0):

Convert dates to Double

```vb
rg.AutoFilter 25, "<=" & CDbl(DateSerial(2023, 12, 30)), xlAnd, "<>" & CDbl(DateSerial(2022, 12, 31))
rg.AutoFilter 26, "<=" & CDbl(Date + 7), xlOr, "unconfirmed"
rg.AutoFilter 27, "<=" & CDbl(Date - 5)
```